# Pokemon Go Capture Issue

Tags: pokemon-go

Well , Ive been in a train for 15 minutes and everytime I try to catch a pokemon They Run away
Please Help !

Comment: Did you GPS spoof?

Comment: yep hahahahahaha ha

Comment: then you're just soft banned for a bit

Answer (score 2):

Pokemon have a different chance of fleeing based on a few factors like their CP, their species, and your level (as you level up, lower-CP Pokemon will flee more often).

As far as I have seen, you will *always* have at least one chance to capture the Pokemon - you can miss as many times as you want, and the Pokemon will flee only after it has broken out of a ball for the first time. So take your time and do everything you can to ensure the first ball is a success:

- Use the best Pokeball you have. Great Balls become available at level 12 and Ultra Balls at level 20.
- Use Razz Berries. They become unlocked at level 8 and will make Pokemon more likely to stay inside the ball.
- Throw the ball only when the circle is as small as possible, and try to hit the inside of the circle. You'll know you got it right if you see Nice, Great, or Excellent come up.

Having said this, powerful enough Pokemon can escape the first throw even with all precautions in place. That's just part of the game!